# Оставить без изменнения текущую страницу ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Проблема в следующем, все данные выведены в таблицу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть кнопка VNC, все хорошо и она работает

```
<td>@Html.ActionLink("VNC", "VNC", new { id = items.id })</td>
```

контроллер у меня такой

```
public void VNC (int? id)
{
  computer computer = db.computers.Find(id);
  Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC4\vncviewer.exe", computer.ipAdr);
}
```

Но как сделать так, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку VNC он не пытался открыть по ID  новую страницу и оставлял текущую страницу без изменений. Сейчас происходит как на картинке ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Процесс vncviewer.exe запускается *на сервере*, вы уверены, что именно это нужно сделать? Сейчас у вас все работает, поскольку сервер запущен на localhost, но как только вы перенесете его на другую машину в сети, vnc-клиент запускаться будет на ней, а не у пользователя с браузером.

Comment: Кстати а как сделать,чтобы он с локальной машины запускался? Спасибо ,что заметили. Если,что я создам отдельный вопрос по этой теме.

Comment: к сожалению, это не так просто. Для хрома придется писать расширение, для IE - использовать ActiveX.

Comment: а если установить VNC на сервер? И типа с него запускать. Все в это одной локальной сети в одном домене

Comment: тогда вам придется и браузер запускать на сервере (например, через rdp-подключение) - теряются преимущества клиент-серверной архитектуры.

Comment: можете попробовать использовать [`@Ajax.ActionLink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можете попробовать вот так:

### View page code:

```
<td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="VNC('@items.id')">VNC</a></td>
```

### Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function VNC(itemId){
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("VNC","VNC")",
            type: "POST",
            data: { id: itemId },
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)  {
                alert("Error" + errorThrown)
            },
            success: function(data){
                //Ничего не делать
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

### Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult VNC (int? id)
{
    computer computer = db.computers.Find(id);
    Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC4\vncviewer.exe", computer.ipAdr);
    return Json(true);           
}
```