# Запуск exe файла с сервера IIS из ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

Проблема в следующем, в локальной сети поднят IIS и на нем я публикую сайты ASP MVC.

Создал директорию на сайте EXE

```
Devices device = db.Devices.Find(id);           

Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC4\vncviewer.exe", device.ipAdr);
System.Diagnostics.Process process1 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

process1.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Request.MapPath("~/EXE/vncviewer.exe");

process1.StartInfo.FileName = Request.MapPath("~/EXE/vncviewer.exe");

process1.StartInfo.Arguments = device.ipAdr;
process1.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;


process1.WaitForExit();
process1.Close();
```

на локальной машине все работает без проблем. Ну как только публикую на сервер, ничего не происходит. Я думаю нужно сделать настройки на стороне сервера. Но не знаю какие.

Comment: проверьте права пользователя от которого происходит запуск и может быть это поможет вам http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532769/how-to-start-a-process-as-administrator-mode-in-c-sharp

Comment: Вам же в прошлом вопросе ещё написали, " Для хрома придется писать расширение, для IE - использовать ActiveX."

Comment: Почему вы два раза используете `Process.Start`?

Comment: Какую проблему вы пытаетесь решить? vncviewer.exe - это UI приложение. IIS - сервис без доступа к десктопу. В лучшем случае - VNC будет висеть в фоне на сервере (пользователь, особенно со стороны браузера, его не увидит - это вообще физически другая машина). В худшем - просто тихо упадет при старте.

Comment: и, судя по http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517319/ - VNC у вас запускается. проблема актуальна?

Comment: Вы действительно думаете, что радикально поменять суть вопроса после того, как на него дано три ответа и объявлена награда - это хорошая идея? Теперь есть два отличных варианта - или вы откатываете правку, возвращая вопрос к первоначальной формулировке, или все ответы подлежат удалению как "не является ответом"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Код запуска процесса отрабатывает на сервере. Соответственно, VNC запускается на сервере, в неинтерактивной сессии.

> на локальной машине все работает без проблем

На локальной сайт у вас скорее всего запущен под IIS Express, который выполняется в текущей сессии пользователя. Т.е.

- Вы вызываете действие через браузер
- Ваш код выполняется в IIS Express, запускает VNC.exe в той же сессии, в которой запущен IIS
- Окно VNC появляется у вас перед глазами ("все работает!")

> как только публикую на сервер, ничего не происходит

- Вы вызываете действие через браузер
- Ваш код выполняется в IIS на сервере, , запускает VNC.exe в той же сессии, в которой запущен IIS - в неинтерактивной сессии на сервере.
- "Неинтерактивная" означает что окно не показывается пользователю. "на сервере" означает что пользователь на клиентской стороне вообще никак его не увидит.

Никакими настройками на стороне сервера это решить нельзя. Витихаря скачать запустить EXE-файл на сторону клиента - тоже - все современные браузеры будут активно этому препятствовать.

Возможные варианты - завернуть запуск VNC + обертку для его запуска с нужными параметрами во что-то типа ClickOnce или Squirrel (It’s like ClickOnce but Works). Поставить на странице ссылку на скачиваение обертки + инструкцию по запуску и надеятся что пользователь не побоится запустить ее.

Answer (score 1):

В исходном коде - process1 нигде не запускается.

```
Devices device = db.Devices.Find(id);           

var process1 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

process1.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Request.MapPath("~/EXE/vncviewer.exe");
process1.StartInfo.FileName = Request.MapPath("~/EXE/vncviewer.exe");

process1.StartInfo.Arguments = device.ipAdr;
process1.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;

process1.Start();

process1.WaitForExit();
process1.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня была почти такая же проблема, не запускался `word.exe`. С локалки все работало, но после публикации, не было доступа к файлу. Проблема была решена добавлением этой строки в "`<system.web> </system.web`", который дает права клиентам на запуск "`*.exe`" файлов на сервере.

```
<identity impersonate="true" 
      userName="username"
      password="password"/>
```

Притом, у того пользователя, которого вы добавите, должны быть права администратора.

Comment: Добрый день.Спасибо.Пишу туда свои учетные данные выскакивает Ошибка конфигурации  Не удалось создать токен пользователя Windows из учетных данных пользователя. Если пишу учетку с доменом то выдает  - Требуемый уровень олицетворения не обеспечен, или обеспеченный уровень неверен. Куда копать?

Comment: А ваш аккаунт точно администратор?

Comment: Да я администратор домена. Просто думаю, надо сделать настройки на стороне IIS? Но не совсем понимаю где

Comment: Я извиняюсь, ну эти ошибки выдает при запуске на локальной машины, как только загружаю на сервак , все ок. Но при попытке запустить с кнопки идет вечный запрос

Comment: держите два web.config файла, один на сервере с этими конфигурациями и другой с вашими конфигурациями с которыми работает на локалке.

Answer (score 0):

Запускать исполняемые файлы через сайт - практически всегда плохая идея.

В вашем случае нужно сначала включить доменную авторизацию и запретить анонимную.
Затем включить персонификацию пользователей в web.config как было показано выше.

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

И на сервере необходимо настроить разрешение на запуск пользователями приложений, которые вы вызываете.

Более правильный подход состоит в создании сервиса, который будет исполняться на сервере и запускать нужные вам приложения по некому триггеру, который вы сможете задавать через сайт. Допустим, на сайте пишете в базу или файл некое значение, которое мониторит сервис, и запускается при получении этого значения.

Comment: Было бы хорошо если бы описали где это все выполняется на iis

Comment: Включить доменную авторизацию на IIS можно через Web.config, который лежит в корне сайта. Это делается так: <system.web><identity impersonate="true" />
    <authentication mode="Windows">  </authentication></system.web>

Comment: Да все хорошо, но только запуск происходит на сервере, а мне нужно,чтобы на клиенте запустилось

Comment: На клиенте вы не сможете запустить программу которая попросту у него нет, он должен загрузить и сам запустить программу.

Comment: @shatoidil об этом вам писали еще в вашем предыдущем вопросе, в комментариях.